# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type java.awt.print.Book to Book

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

```
@Service
public class LMSService {

    @Autowired
    private BookInterface a;

    private Collection<Books1> findBooks(){
    List<Books1> books=new ArrayList<Books1>();
    for(Books1 booke : a.findAll())
    {
        books.add(booke);
    }
    return books;
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface BookInterface extends CrudRepository<Books1,Long>{

}
```

---

`a.findAll()` method gives the error

Comment: Read the title of your question carefully. It contains the answer. Look at your imports. Do you really want to use classes from the java.awt packages?

Comment: You need to improve your question to avoid it being closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the generic arguments

```java
CrudRepository<Books1, Integer>
```

Comment: You need to read the comment by JB.

Comment: JB's comment was misleading. My answer was straight to the point.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that there is a problem with Long vs Integer. Nothing. The question title talks about a class cast exception because importing a Book class out of awt. The facts simply do not up here, at all.